# What is wrong with this xsl:key?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to match 'data' from several different xml tags with a `<xsl:key>`, but it does not seem to work the way I understand it should..

Here is a sample xml:

```
<root>
    <parts>
      <part class="Button" id="b1"/>
      <part class="Button" id="b2"/>
      <part class="Label" id="text"/>
      <part class="div" id="div1">
        <part class="Checkbox" id="cb1">
          <part class="CheckboxItem" id="item1"/>
          <part class="CheckboxItem" id="item2"/>
        </part>
      </part>
    </parts>
    <properties>
      <property part-name="b1" name="label">button 1</property>
      <property part-name="b2" name="label">button 2</property>
      <property part-name="text" name="label">
        <reference const="text"/>
      </property>
      <property part-name="cb1" name="label">
        <reference const="cb1"/>
      </property>
      <property part-name="item1" name="label">
        <reference const="item1"/>
      </property>
      <property part-name="item2" name="label">
        <reference const="item2"/>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <content>
      <constant id="cb1" value="Favourite Ice Cream?"/>
      <constant id="item1" value="Vanilla"/>
      <constant id="item2" value="wChocholate"/>
    </content>
</root>
```

Some brief explanation - `<part>` has unique `id`. This `id` is matched in the `<property>` tag with `part-name` attribute.

I have no problem with the two 'button' parts and they properties, a.k.a. - labels in this particular case. This is the type of key I use for this scenario:

```
<xsl:key name="Labels" match="property[@name='label']" use="@part-name"/>
```

and then in my XSLT I get the value with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('Labels', @id)"/>
```

But then I am trying something different, where I want to extract the `value` from the `<content>` tag and match it to each respective `part` according to the unique `id`.

What I have so far is this:

```
<xsl:key name="Contents" match="property[@part-name]" use="content/constant[@id]" />
```

calling it later with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('Contents', @part-name)/@value"/>
```

So, I would be glad to hear what's wrong with my second key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to extract the `value` from the `<content>` tag

I think you want to extract the `value` from the `<constant>` element inside `<content>`. If so, your key needs to look like this:

```
<xsl:key name="Contents" match="constant" use="@id"/>
```

With this in place, the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('Contents', 'cb1')/@value" />
```

will return:

```
Favourite Ice Cream?
```

--

The way you have it:

```
<xsl:key name="Contents" match="property[@part-name]" use="content/constant[@id]" />
```

cannot work, because (a) you are matching the wrong element (you don't want to lookup data from `property`); and (b) the element you *are* matching does not have the designated `use` node: the `property` element has no `content` child.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but what if I have to explicitly use the `reference` tags inside the `property` tags? Is it possible to construct such a key that considers these elements instead of the direct approach?

Comment: @ldimitrov It depends on your context: when you are in the context of `property`, then `<xsl:value-of select="key('Contents', reference/@const)/@value"/>` will return `"Vanilla"` if the value of current `property/reference/@const` is `"item1"`.